# why do i keep getting this error( Field 'id' expected a number but got ''. ) each time users like a post from their own timeline?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here is the users account view that i want users to be able to like their post from, it has really been a challenge to get my head around this. would appreciate some help.

```
def account_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    - Logic here is kind of tricky
        is_self
        is_friend
            -1: NO_REQUEST_SENT
            0: THEM_SENT_TO_YOU
            1: YOU_SENT_TO_THEM
    """
    context = {}
    user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
    try:
        account = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.")
    if account:
        context['id'] = account.id
        context['username'] = account.username
        context['bio'] = account.bio
        context['get_full_name'] = account.get_full_name
        context['email'] = account.email
        context['profile_pic'] = account.profile_pic.url
        context['cover_image'] = account.cover_image.url
        context['city'] = account.city
        context['country'] = account.country
        context['gender'] = account.gender
        context['hide_email'] = account.hide_email

        post_id = request.GET.get("likeId", "")
        try:
            post_id = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            liked= False
            like = Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
   


        try:
            post_list = Post.objects.filter(user_name=account)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            post_list = Post(user_name=account)
            save.post_list()
        posts = post_list.all()
        context['posts'] = posts
```

Here is my like view, how best do can i accomplish users and friends being able to like their post from their own profile or timeline ?

```
def like(request):
    post_id = request.GET.get("likeId", "")
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    liked= False
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        liked = True
        Like.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
    resp = {
        'liked':liked
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type = "application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs either because `likeId` is sent as an empty string `http://url_path?likeId=`, or (most probably) because it is not present in the `request.GET` at all.

You've used `request.GET.get("likeId", "")` so the default value is `""`.
Next, the code runs `post_id = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)`. It's forbidden to pass a string to a `pk` filter, hence the error. So, verify the `likeId` is indeed send in the request and it's an actual Post.id (check for possible typos). **Maybe** you've meant to use `request.POST` instead?

Generally, it's a bad idea to use `dict.get()` where you clearly DO need an value. Also, there should be some validation in place to ensure the `likeId` is a valid integer. I would recommend validating input parameters with a form, but a manual approach is also possible.

```
try:
    post_id = int(request.GET["likeId")
except (KeyError, ValueError):
    return HttpResponse('Provide a valid likeId integer', status_code=404)
```